# What does 'refer' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I encountered a sentence and don't understand the meaning of 'refer' here even if I looked it up in the dic.

"A snowball strategy occurred as administrators were asked to refer special education and general education teachers."

If anyone knows, please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: The example seems to be incomplete. What is the source, and can you add additional context?

Comment: I agree that it would help to have more context, it seem there might be a missing preposition or something. From what's given, perhaps it means "recommend". People can "refer someone" which means to recommend someone, for example: to refer a doctor to a sick patient.

Comment: Actually..it is edited by me and I made the sentence shorter from the original. It's from "American Secondary Education" and the complete sentence is this. "A snowball strategy, or network or chaining process (Patton, 2002), occurred as administrators were asked to refer special education and general education teachers, parents of students with high incidence disabilities, and students with high incidence disabilities. In all three cases, the administrators made contact with the remaining participants. "

Comment: And I got this from a Corpus.  If I add more contents before and after this sentence. They show like this.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence

> A snowball strategy occurred as administrators were asked to **refer** special education and general education teachers.

means nominating or mentioning *someone* for inclusion.

> I **referred** a friend to the club for membership.

The "snowball strategy" in your example is

> [snowball sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_sampling) a non-probability sampling technique where existing study subjects recruit future subjects from among their acquaintances.

The administrators were asked to suggest teachers to be included.  One of the main problems with this technique is

> [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias)

since the administrators are playing a curatorial role.